# images uploaded to S3 Bucket not viewable on browser

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using serverless framework + angular. I can see images being uploaded to S3 bucket but what I want to download them, the images appear to be a tiny square. I am thinking my angular code might be the issue:

upload.service.ts

```
uploadToS3(uploadURL: string, file : any): Observable<any>{
    const formData = new FormData();   
    formData.append("image", file); 
    return this.http.put(uploadURL, formData);
  }
```

where uploadURL is a pre-signed S3 URL.

upload.component.ts:

```
   file : File = null;

     setFileBeingUploaded(event: any) { 
    this.file = event.target.files[0]; 
     } 

     putToS3 = (uploadURL: string) => {

        this.service.uploadToS3(uploadURL, this.file).subscribe(data=>{

        console.log('file uploaded successfully');
  
    }, err=>{
     console.log( err);
    })
   }
```

Now I can see the file uploaded on S3 and permissions are well but when I open it, all i see is a square as follows (turns out I can't upload the image here...encoding error?)

when I upload the file to fotoforensics, I am getting:

```
The submitted file (1-2-14.jpg) could not be analyzed: Not a JPEG, PNG, or WebP.
```

Comment: How do you process the image before putting into the bucket?

Comment: @Marcin oh i am not doing any processing. I figured it would be just uploading (since postman uploading to the pre-signed URL works right away). Let me take a look, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if object is actually not broken, go to S3 and use download option to download your file.

If it's S3 permissions issue, then you would not be able to upload the file, not even a square. I'm not familiar with angular though but you could try to create separate simple file which would just do the upload w/o the rest of your project. Have working example of upload and then try to move that to the project. Check file size too. It may provide some debug insights. Good luck :)

[image]

Comment: thanks @Lukas Liesis...gave me the way to debug. Buffer is the way to go instead of formdata which I have always used